# How can I show a loading gif when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show a loading gif:

1. when a link is clicked
2. when a link is clicked with a specific css class

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Show loading gif on click all links: `$("a").click(function() { $("#loading").show(); }`

Comment: It does not work like this. Please ask your question in a more specific way. A codepen or jsfiddle would help in these cases.